# remove different admin menu for specific users

Tags: plugin-development, menus, hooks, actions

Initially I intended to fetch user ID so I could show/hide certain menu groups in my plugin based on user status (which I added as a meta).

The problem is that I can't use `wp_get_current_user` and `get_current_user_id` returns 0.

Is there any other way to get this ID? Or is there another way to hide/show menu based on logged in user status?

The structure almost looks like this.

```
add_action("admin_menu","show_menu");
function show_menu(){
    //create menu1;
    //create menu2;

    if () //check user status
        //create menu3
}
```

Comment: Which menus are we talking about? Navigation menus that are displayed on front-end or menu pages that are visible in back-end?

Comment: [Before the `plugins_loaded` action it returns 0.](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/#comment-2507)

Answer (score 0):

You mention user 'status'....are you looking to show/hide the menu for classes of users (by role/capability) rather than individual users (by ID)?

I do something similar so that users below a level cannot access certain back-end menu items, using current_user_can and !current_user_can.

As an example, this checks to see if a user is an Editor or higher, and if not does not allow the user to see ANY Posts except their own (default WP behavior is to show all Posts but only allow them to edit their own, we don't want them to even see others' Posts).

```
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'posts_for_current_contributor' );
function posts_for_current_contributor() {
    global $user_ID;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'delete_others_posts' ) ) {
       if ( ! isset( $_GET['author'] ) ) {
          wp_redirect( add_query_arg( 'author', $user_ID ) );
          exit;
       }
   }

}
```

You can learn more about Roles & Capabilities with some other examples here: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities